# Trouble with JavaScript regex code to match characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like help with solving a problem using regular expressions.

I've written the following JavaScript code:

```
var s = '/Date(1341118800000)/';
var regex = new RegExp('^/Date\(\d+\)/$');
if ( typeof s === 'string' && s.match(regex) )
    s = 'abc';
alert (s);
```

I have written a regex that I want to match strings that begin with the following exact characters: `/Date(` followed by one or more digits, followed by the exact characters `)/` and nothing more.

In the above JavaScript code, I expect that the string 'abc' should be assigned to `s`, but at the conclusion of this code, the value of `s` is '/Date(1341118800000)/'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to use abc when there is no match?

Comment: In this case, if the string `s` matches the regular expression, the string 'abc' should be assigned to `s`.

Comment: Why not just `s = '/Date(1341118800000)/' == s ? "abc" : s;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape slashes are already consumed by the string, i.e. `"\(" === "("`. The resulting unescaped string is passed to `new RegExp`, which interprets `(` as a special character.

You should use a regular expression literal and escape the `/`s as well:

```
var regex = /^\/Date\(\d+\)\/$/;
```

To test whether a string matches, you can use:

```
regex.test(s);
```

Comment: I tried your fix and it seems to work.  However, I was following a "cheat sheet" here: http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/.  The "cheat sheet" does not include `/` as a character that should be escaped.  Is that an error on the cheat sheet, or is it specific to regex in JavaScript that `/` must be escaped?

Comment: @Daniel Allen Langdon: Is that sheet JavaScript specific? In JavaScript, regexp literals are enclosed by `/`, so you need to escape them if you want to use them literally. (The sheet also e.g. says `>` needs escaping but it doesn't in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"/^/Date\(\d+\)/$/"` converts to `"/^/Date(d+)/$/"` in javascript.

`"/^/Date\(\d+\)/$/" == "/^/Date(d+)/$/" // returns true`

So just escape the backspace, `\`, to fix the problem.

`var regex = new RegExp('^/Date\\(\\d+\\)/$');`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this code:

```
var s = '/Date(1341118800000)/';
s = s.match(/^\/Date\((\d+)\)\/$/)[1];
alert(s);
```

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sev23/).