# Shouldn't this RegExp work?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
testString = "something://something/task?type=Checkin";

patt = new RegExp("something\/(\w*)\?");
match = patt.exec(testString);
document.querySelector('#resultRegexp').innerHTML = match[1];
```

I want to capture `task` So shouldn't this RegExp work?

I am grabbing any alphanumeric character up until the question mark... and capturing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/h4yhc/2/

Comment: Seems to have the same solution as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693882/trouble-with-javascript-regex-code-to-match-characters-and-numbers/11693936#11693936.

Comment: @stevether I did. It's in the fiddle

Comment: Please edit your post to put the code here when possible. It's preferred because a) if the external site is unavailable and most of your content is there, your question becomes meaningless; b) it makes people leave this site  just to see what you're asking, and c) it's unsearchable because the content isn't here. At least post the most relevant parts here, and then use the link for something like "Full source available  <here>".

Comment: @KenWhite I agree, updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to escape the slash in regex literals, and the backslash in string literals which you create regexes from:

```
var patt = /something\/(\w*)\?/g;
// or
var patt = new RegExp("something/(\\w*)\\?", 'g');
```

I strongly recommend the first version, it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be enough: `(\w*)\?`, since / is not captured by \w and the only ? in the string is after your target string.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
patt = new RegExp(".*/(\\w*)\\?");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FJcfd/

Answer (score 0):

try with this: `var pat = /something:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/)+(\w+)\?(\w+=\w+)/;`

it can match string such as:

```
something://something/task?type=Checkin
something://something/foo/task?type=Checkin
something://something/foo/bar/task1?type3=Checkin4
```